# Updating TOR screwed up my client : "Download Error: 404"

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, browser, tor

it's been ages that Tor browser has that update pop up. Today, because the browser was lagging and freezing/skipping frames while streaming videos, I gave it a shot and updated, it warned me it'll close my running instance and reinstall in the background.

1. I'm on debian/ubuntu 20.04 KDE. Now the taskbar shortcut won't launch, only open a tiny window showing "Download Error: 404".
2. When I go to the app menu, sub-menu "Internet", I get the remaining apps "Tor Browser Launcher Settings" and "Tor Browser". I also have a third app, called "Tor Browser" as well. All have the same logo. The two remaining ones lead to that tiny error window, while the third one does launch Tor browser, from which I'm able to post this thread.
3. I now have "two" Tor, because the third app I'm able to launch is downloaded from torproject website, then I extracted their folder somewhere, opened the terminal here, and did `$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app` . So I guess the two former apps were pulled from the apt repository (because installed via the "Discover" KDE GUI).
4. Before downloading a new instance from torproject website, I tried repairing with `sudo apt remove tor torbrowser-launcher -y` without the `--purge` to conserve my bookmarks hopefully, then reinstalled it with `sudo apt install tor torbrowser-launcher -y` . Which went well, as far as terminal is outputing. But still that error when clicking on the apps...
5. While right clicking on the non-working "Tor Browser" app and the working one, I notice a difference in commands. The working one does `sh -c '"/home/user/softwares/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ ! -x "/home/user/softwares/tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k` , whereas the old apt-pulled app has `torbrowser-launcher %u` .So out of curiosity, I opened a terminal and typed `$ torbrowser-launcher` , and there I got this output :

> ```
> Tor Browser Launcher
> By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
> version 0.3.2
> https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
> Downloading Tor Browser for the first time.
> Downloading https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
> Latest version: 12.0
> Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0/tor-browser-linux64-12.0_en-US.tar.xz.asc
> Download Error: 404
> ```

SO what's wrong with the old instance please ? The URL from which it's trying to pull ?? I'm asking this because on the fresh torproject-pulled instance, the bookmarks I've saved on the apt-pulled browser are missing...

Also when attaching the taskbar shortcut from the working instance, it always end up launching the old instance, hence popping that error window. So I always have to dig into the app menu to click on the third app.

**If you guys know how to restore the old instance, OR extract my profile from the old instance to inject in the new one, I'd be thankful**

(Found this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=804184 but I quite don't understand since their build seems to be some hardened one...

Also when I do `echo $PATH` and guess that the `torbrowser-launcher` file will be in `/usr/`, and search for that file to modify the URL end from "_en-US" to "_ALL", I really can't find such file to modify. Only some python script which does nothing but import some torbrowser-launcher module...)

Comment: Please provide clear OS & release details...   You should have no issues for most releases, but we can't know about specific OS & release until you provide that necessary detail.  FYI:  Tor browser does work, I use it very regularly (*not quite daily*) and speak with a maintainer somewhat regularly

Comment: Thank you for answering, done : ubuntu 20.04,  fresh install of tor is v12.0, broken one I don't know what version I was using but now that I tried to repair it I pulled whatever latest version from apt repo to this date. Hopefully it's 12.0 as well.

Comment: Glad to learn it, FYI a parallel investigation is ongoing here : https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/zic3ta/updating_tor_screwed_up_my_client_download_error/

Comment: This issue maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077 which currently is IN PROGRESS with regards fix.

Comment: Upstream issues in Debian have been resolved, and Thomas (teward) now has resolved this issue on *lunar*, and SRU (*stable release update*) request for released products has been started.

Answer (score 19):

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, latest update. Installed the `torbrowser-launcher` from the official repo.

Doing this changes should make the `torbrowser-launcher` works as expected. But before you do, you must remove this directories `~/.cache/torbrowser`, `~/.local/share/torbrowser`, `~/.config/torbrowser` as they save information for the launcher and the fix won't work using those.

Be aware that if you have a working Tor Browser installation, you will lose your settings and working installations. Using this fix for the `torbrowser-launcher` doesn't take into account existing installations, but gives an idea on why the launcher fails to download the current version.

First change this line on `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py` on line 171, you will need root access to make changes to this file:

```py
if hasattr(self, 'settings') and self.settings['force_en-US']:
    language = 'en-US'
else:
    #language = self.language
    language = "ALL"
```

Commented out the variable `language` and set it again with the value `"ALL"`, that way the launcher will look for the correct signatures and tarballs files in the mirror.

Also made a change in line 227 of the same file, this time when setting up the variables to the install location, the launcher will refer to the language setting and set it as part of the directory installation, but the actual package downloaded by the launcher will refer to the directory as `tor-browser` and not by `tor-browser_ALL` as the launcher would expect it to do:

```py
                "tbb": {
                    "changelog": tbb_local
                    + "/tbb/"
                    + self.architecture
                    + "/tor-browser"
                    #+ "/tor-browser_"
                    #+ language
                    + "/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/ChangeLog.txt",
                    "dir": tbb_local + "/tbb/" + self.architecture,
                    "dir_tbb": tbb_local
                    + "/tbb/"
                    + self.architecture
                    + "/tor-browser",
                    #+ "/tor-browser_"
                    #+ language,
                    "start": tbb_local
                    + "/tbb/"
                    + self.architecture
                    + "/tor-browser"
                    #+ "/tor-browser_"
                    #+ language
                    + "/start-tor-browser.desktop",
},
```

Here there are three entries that must be changed. All of them refers to `/tor-browser_` + `language` as part of the installation directory. It must be changed to `/tor-browser` and attention on the second entry as it must end with `,`.

This fix is terrible, it doesn't remove the language setting at all, just fixes it in order to make it work with what is available in the mirror. I guess we need to wait for the devs to make this fix on the repo package, by that time those changes will be rewritten and hopefully still works.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Updated the line for the second fix and updated the code block. Again, we shouldn't have to do that. If you choose to do this fix, pay close attention.

Comment: That was fantastic.

Comment: It's stupid that this is required

Comment: Think this just worked for me too. Basically new ubuntu install, few different versions of Python but Python3 was where tor was installed to. One thing, I wonder if adding the Tor browser repo: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa and updating/installing using that would have fixed it? As found on linuxize.com tutorial.

Comment: nope, still gives a 404 for me

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I see locale/language as a common thread in all these answers, which is cool but...any insight onto why language is causing a problem in the first place? Is it bad case handling when the default language is not en-US or something?

Answer (score 8):

```bash
sudo sed -i 's|self.language =.*|self.language = "ALL"|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py
rm -rf ~/{cache,.local/share,.config}/torbrowser
ln -s ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL
torbrowser-launcher
```

This complete code above should be enough.

---

Running `/home/user/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL/start-tor-browser.desktop`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 442, in success
    self.run_task()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 301, in run_task
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 477, in run
    if not self.check_min_version():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 465, in check_min_version
    for line in open(self.common.paths["tbb"]["changelog"], "rb").readlines():
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/ChangeLog.txt'
```

```
ln -s ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64{tor-browser,tor-browser_ALL}
```

and run `torbrowser-launcher`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
 sudo sed -i 's|self.language =.*|self.language = "ALL"|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py
```

Use this command in terminal to set the self language from common.py

hope it works I have tested it in Ubuntu 22.04.

ps: I found this command from snap comments and worked successfully for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. In /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py find and change to the following statements

   ```
        ...
        tarball_filename = (
            "tor-browser-linux64-12.0a5_ALL.tar.xz"
        )
       ...
        self.paths["tarball_url"] = (
            "{0}torbrowser/12.0a5/" + tarball_filename
        )
        ...
        self.paths["sig_url"] = (
           "{0}torbrowser/12.0a5/" + tarball_filename + ".asc"
        )
   ```

Where *12.0a5* is a version I found at https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/

2. Then rename the directory

`mv ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser/ ~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US`

Where `_en-Us` is my locale, you may have something different.

3. Finally, launch the torbrowser-launcher

Answer (score 1):

Same thing on Mint 21.5

Removed the following folders:

```
~/.cache/torbrowser
~/.local/share/torbrowser
~/.config/torbrowser
```

As Fellipe Weno said on his post if you have a working Tor Browser installation, you might lose the settings.

With root you must change  the common.py file located at  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py

```
if hasattr(self, 'settings') and self.settings['force_en-US']:
    language = 'en-US'
else:
    #language = self.language
    language = "ALL" #ADD THIS LINE
```

I also modified the tor-browser_ to tor-browser as Fellipe mentions

It worked on linux mint

Regards

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic at this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you get download error 404, run this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's|self.language =.*|self.language = "ALL"|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py
```

After reopening Tor it will download and work.

Comment: As written this is not answer. Some references would help. How do I know doing this will not mess up my system?

Comment: I'm confused by the answers: there seem to be different ways of fixing the 404 e.g. ones for Mint which may not work for standard Ubuntu 22.04. What is the definitive method for standard Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: this may work but may not resolve properly for 13 and up. If you apply it you can see the error. With a bit of search in the mentioned common.py file you can make it match the proper file ( remove _ALL ). There is a bug that tracks this, help if you can : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077