# torbrowser-launcher first time running giving a 404 error because indeed the file in question is not there to download

Tags: tor

I know there are lots of questions, some well-answered, about 404 errors on torbrowser-launcher. They didn't seem to hit the spot.

I have 2 linux Ubuntu computers each running 22.04 LTS. I successfully installed Tor on the desktop one. The laptop fails when running torbrowser-launcher with a download error 404.

```
joe@system76-pc:~$ sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libqt5xml5 python3-gpg python3-packaging python3-pyqt5
  python3-pyqt5.sip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libqt5xml5 python3-gpg python3-packaging python3-pyqt5
  python3-pyqt5.sip torbrowser-launcher
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,839 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5xml5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 [124 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libqt5designer5 amd64 5.15.3-1 [2,832 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5sql5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 [123 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libqt5help5 amd64 5.15.3-1 [162 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 [214 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5sql5-sqlite amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 [53.0 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5test5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 [152 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 python3-gpg amd64 1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4 [215 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 python3-packaging all 21.3-1 [30.7 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 python3-pyqt5.sip amd64 12.9.1-1build1 [61.1 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 python3-pyqt5 amd64 5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3 [2,822 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 torbrowser-launcher amd64 0.3.3-6ubuntu1.22.04.1 [50.1 kB]
Fetched 6,839 kB in 3s (2,499 kB/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5xml5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 250160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libqt5xml5_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5designer5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libqt5designer5_5.15.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5designer5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5sql5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libqt5sql5_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5help5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libqt5help5_5.15.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5help5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5printsupport5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libqt5printsupport5_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb 
...
Unpacking libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libqt5sql5-sqlite_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ..
.
Unpacking libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5test5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libqt5test5_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5test5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-gpg.
Preparing to unpack .../07-python3-gpg_1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-gpg (1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-packaging.
Preparing to unpack .../08-python3-packaging_21.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-packaging (21.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pyqt5.sip.
Preparing to unpack .../09-python3-pyqt5.sip_12.9.1-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pyqt5.sip (12.9.1-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pyqt5.
Preparing to unpack .../10-python3-pyqt5_5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pyqt5 (5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package torbrowser-launcher.
Preparing to unpack .../11-torbrowser-launcher_0.3.3-6ubuntu1.22.04.1_amd64.deb 
...
Unpacking torbrowser-launcher (0.3.3-6ubuntu1.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python3-packaging (21.3-1) ...
Setting up python3-gpg (1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4) ...
Setting up python3-pyqt5.sip (12.9.1-1build1) ...
Setting up libqt5test5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5designer5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up libqt5help5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up python3-pyqt5 (5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up torbrowser-launcher (0.3.3-6ubuntu1.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
joe@system76-pc:~$ sudo find / -iname torbrowser-launcher
/usr/share/torbrowser-launcher
/usr/share/doc/torbrowser-launcher
/usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
joe@system76-pc:~$ /usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.3.3
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Creating GnuPG homedir /home/joe/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Downloading Tor Browser for the first time.
Downloading https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
Latest version: 12.0.3
Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.3/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.3_en-US.tar.xz.asc
Download Error: 404
^C
```

I have tried removing and re-installing.
Something curious I noticed after the Downloading Tor Browser the first time. It tries to download this file:
https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.3/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.3_en-US.tar.xz.asc
But at this website: https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.3/ that file name does not exist. So, it really is a 404 file not found error.
The closest file it has is tor-browser-linux64-12.0.3_ALL.tar.xz.asc
(Replaces _en-US with ALL!)
Thank you for any help

Comment: Known issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077

Comment: Upstream issues in Debian have been resolved, and Thomas (teward) now has resolved this issue on *lunar*, and SRU (*stable release update*) request for released products has been started.

Comment: I found this post. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445050/updating-tor-screwed-up-my-client-download-error-404 Following the instructions on the reply worked for me.